# Planning from 32 bit to 64 LTS

Tags: partitioning, upgrade

Quick question, still learning Linux, so any advice is very much appreciated. I currently have 2 computers set-up as servers with one computer (MAIN) acting as DHCP and DNS server, and a second computer (TWO) also has DHCP and DNS servers (with a different range of IPs for wireless). TWO also acts as a rollover in case the MAIN should ever fail. My concern is they both have 32 bit install LTS 18.04 on both.

I'd like to go 20.04 with the next release in April. So I was planning on creating a DHCP a second partition on each computer installing 64 of the next LTS and then copying the relevant etc/ folders to get the DHCP and DNS over to the new partition. Any advice on how to do this painless and any pitfuls I can avoid. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you really asking "what are the settings files that I need to copy?" Or are you asking something else?

Comment: Yes, I suppose that is what I  was asking. And I guessing is there a way to copy of all the settings from 18.04 partition to the new 20.04 partition (knowing that 32 vs 64 I was unsure if there would be an issue). So each partition would be identical in name and Ip, etc.  Thank you.

Comment: I moved a web/file/vpn server from a 32 bit box to a 64 bit box at the 14.04 -> 16.04 transition. I did a fresh install on the 64 bit box, installed the additional software using aptik, and loaded my backups to it. I did not experience any problems because of the word length change. There were some small issues just due to newer s/w versions.